# Multiple VM creation while using Catel with Modern UI

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, catel, modern-ui

I love Catel framework. Modern UI looks pretty good. But I've faced with problem while trying to make them works together.

I've added two catels usercontrols `Home` and `Second` in mui project. The problem is that when transition from `Home` to `Second` performing `HomeViewModel` has been created 3 times.

This behavior caused by next code in `TransitioningContentControl`

```
    private void StartTransition(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        // both presenters must be available, otherwise a transition is useless.
        if (CurrentContentPresentationSite != null && PreviousContentPresentationSite != null) {
            CurrentContentPresentationSite.Content = newContent;

            PreviousContentPresentationSite.Content = oldContent;

            // and start a new transition
            if (!IsTransitioning || RestartTransitionOnContentChange) {
                IsTransitioning = true;
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, NormalState, false);
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, Transition, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

If I comment some lines:

```
private void StartTransition(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        // both presenters must be available, otherwise a transition is useless.
        if (CurrentContentPresentationSite != null && PreviousContentPresentationSite != null) {
            CurrentContentPresentationSite.Content = newContent;

            //PreviousContentPresentationSite.Content = oldContent;

            // and start a new transition
            if (!IsTransitioning || RestartTransitionOnContentChange) {
                IsTransitioning = true;
                //VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, NormalState, false);
                //VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, Transition, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Same transition in this case results in creating `HomeViewModel` 1 times, but I dont want  creating `HomeViewModel` while performing navigation from `Home` control. How can I achieve this?

[Project to taste](http://www55.zippyshare.com/v/80533549/file.html)

Comment: Catel has 3 reasons to create a view model: 

1) The DataContext has changed or 2) The view receives the Loaded event or 3) navigation has completed.

Comment: I have quickly checked with the latest prerelease. It only does 1 additional load where it shouldn't, and that's because the view is loaded again (thus requesting a new view model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible options you can solve this issue:

**1) Use existing feature (CloseViewModelOnUnloaded). Will keep VM alive during transition.**

Then you need this code in TransitioningContentControl.StartTransition

```
var userControl = oldContent as Catel.Windows.Controls.UserControl;
if (userControl != null)
{
    userControl.CloseViewModelOnUnloaded = false;
}

PreviousContentPresentationSite.Content = oldContent;
```

Add this to OnTransitionCompleted:

```
var userControl = PreviousContentPresentationSite.Content as Catel.Windows.Controls.UserControl;
if (userControl != null)
{
    userControl.CloseViewModelOnUnloaded = true;
    var vm = userControl.ViewModel;
    if (vm != null)
    {
        vm.CloseViewModel(true);
    }
}

AbortTransition();
```

**2) Use new feature (PreventViewModelCreation) Will not keep VM alive during transition.**

Then you need this code in TransitioningContentControl.StartTransition

```
var vmContainer = oldContent as IViewModelContainer;
if (vmContainer != null)
{
    vmContainer.PreventViewModelCreation = true;
}

PreviousContentPresentationSite.Content = oldContent;
```

Add this to the OnTransitionCompleted method:

```
var vmContainer = PreviousContentPresentationSite.Content as IViewModelContainer;
if (vmContainer != null)
{
    vmContainer.PreventViewModelCreation = false;
}

AbortTransition();
```